# Fiware-Orion - How to work with attributes values history (lists of values)

Tags: list, attributes, history, fiware, fiware-orion

I want to register some entities in my Orion instance and keep the history of attributes values in a way I can get the list of values of this attributes.

For example, a sensor `S1` measuring temperature of a room hourly should keep a list of values in its `temperature` attribute in a way that every new update should be added in the end of the list.

The `update` operation I am doing now only updates the value, without adding it to some "list". I've read the documentation, but I did not find out some useful information about this. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a good question. You have different options:

1/ Use the STH component to deal with time data series https://github.com/Fiware/context.STH.Comet

2/ Model your entities in Orion using a similar pattern to the one used by the FIWARE Data Models "AirQualityObserved" or "WeatherObserved"

http://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Environment/AirQualityObserved/doc/spec/index.html

i.e. create one entity for each observation and tag it with a "dateObserved" property. Then you can do queries like

http://orion:1026/v2/entities?type=TemperatureObserved&q=room:R1;dateObserved>=2017-01-01&options=values&orderBy=dateObserved

This will provide an ordered array of temperature values measured since the first of January.

Comment: I recommend alternative 1 above. As a complement to this answer, the usage of STH (or, in general, any other hitorical context backend, as they are many: MySQL, HDFS, etc.) requires Cygnus: http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Comment: This is the option that we are working. Could you explain, please, why STH requires Cygnus, @fgalan ? I did not see any mention to it in the README file of Comet (STH).

Comment: Hi Dalton, all! The STH does not require Cygnus to work :) It is just one of the 2 ways to generate aggregated data in the STH. Further information at http://fiware-sth-comet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data-storage/index.html which by the way is referenced from https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet#api-walkthrough ;) Thanks!

Comment: Nevertheless, if you use Cygnus you'll benefit from a reliable mechanism of sending context information from Orion to STH, batching capabilities improving the performance and many others. Let's say directly connecting Orion and STH is for testing purposes, and using Cygnus in between them is for production environments.